# Generating java class file at compile time

Tags: java, android

I want to generate java class file at compile time. What i want to achieve is auto generate a file while creating new `Activity` or `Fragment` etc from android studio. I tried creating file from `gradle` but for this i have enter file name and sync every time i create `Activity` or `Fragment`. I tried creating file from `java` but not at run time.

For example:

While creating MainActivity i want to create java class/interface file mainInterface.java.

All i want to know when to trigger a set of codes that will create a file or any other methods.

Is there any way for achieving this. I have heard about creating `IntelliJ` plugins but i got no idea about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. I think this is too broad.

Comment: @GhostCat does that help?

Comment: Not really. Maybe you should rather describe what kind of source code you want to generate. I know that IntelliJ has a lot of "code generation" support ...

Comment: @GhostCat i want to simply create a java class file for eg when i create a `MainActivity` then i want to generate a MainInterface java class.

Comment: @ArjunGurung try to add an example and describe the thing that you are trying to do in details. For Example: if I need to compile example.java into example.class at run-time i could use reflection with  JavaCompiler class

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  At the moment it seems like an X/Y problem.